# PostgreSQL - Working with array of thousands of elements

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance

I'm looking to select rows based on whether a column is contained in a large list of values that I pass as an integer array.

Here's the query I currently use:

```
SELECT item_id, other_stuff, ...
FROM (
    SELECT
        -- Partitioned row number as we only want N rows per id
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item_id ORDER BY start_date) AS r,
        item_id, other_stuff, ...
    FROM mytable
    WHERE
        item_id = ANY ($1) -- Integer array
        AND end_date > $2
    ORDER BY item_id ASC, start_date ASC, allowed ASC
) x
WHERE x.r <= 12
```

The table is structured as such:

```
    Column     |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default 
---------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 item_id       | integer                     |           | not null | 
 allowed       | boolean                     |           | not null | 
 start_date    | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | 
 end_date      | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | 
 ...


 Indexes:
    "idx_dtr_query" btree (item_id, start_date, allowed, end_date)
    ...
```

I came up with this index after trying different ones and running `EXPLAIN` on the query. This one was the most efficient for both querying and sorting. Here is the explain analyze of the query:

```
Subquery Scan on x  (cost=0.56..368945.41 rows=302230 width=73) (actual time=0.021..276.476 rows=168395 loops=1)
  Filter: (x.r <= 12)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 90275
  ->  WindowAgg  (cost=0.56..357611.80 rows=906689 width=73) (actual time=0.019..248.267 rows=258670 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using idx_dtr_query on mytable  (cost=0.56..339478.02 rows=906689 width=73) (actual time=0.013..130.362 rows=258670 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((item_id = ANY ('{/* 15,000 integers */}'::integer[])) AND (end_date > '2018-03-30 12:08:00'::timestamp without time zone))
Planning time: 30.349 ms
Execution time: 284.619 ms
```

The issue is that the int array can contain up to 15,000 elements or so and the query gets quite slow in this case (about 800ms on my laptop, a recent Dell XPS).

I thought passing the int array as a parameter could be slow so, and considering the list of ids can be stored beforehand in the database I tried doing this. I stored them in an array in another table and used `item_id = ANY (SELECT UNNEST(item_ids) FROM ...)`, which was slower than my current approach. I also tried storing them row by row and using `item_id IN (SELECT item_id FROM ...)`, which was even slower, even with only the rows relevant to my test case in the table.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Update: following [Evan's comments](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/203055/137478), another approach I tried: each item is part of several groups, so instead of passing group's item ids, I tried adding the group ids in mytable:

```
    Column     |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default 
---------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 item_id       | integer                     |           | not null | 
 allowed       | boolean                     |           | not null | 
 start_date    | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | 
 end_date      | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | 
 group_ids     | integer[]                   |           | not null | 
 ...

 Indexes:
    "idx_dtr_query" btree (item_id, start_date, allowed, end_date)
    "idx_dtr_group_ids" gin (group_ids)
    ...
```

New query ($1 is the targeted group id):

```
SELECT item_id, other_stuff, ...
FROM (
    SELECT
        -- Partitioned row number as we only want N rows per id
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item_id ORDER BY start_date) AS r,
        item_id, other_stuff, ...
    FROM mytable
    WHERE
        $1 = ANY (group_ids)
        AND end_date > $2
    ORDER BY item_id ASC, start_date ASC, allowed ASC
) x
WHERE x.r <= 12
```

Explain analyze:

```
Subquery Scan on x  (cost=123356.60..137112.58 rows=131009 width=74) (actual time=811.337..1087.880 rows=172023 loops=1)
  Filter: (x.r <= 12)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 219726
  ->  WindowAgg  (cost=123356.60..132199.73 rows=393028 width=74) (actual time=811.330..1040.121 rows=391749 loops=1)
        ->  Sort  (cost=123356.60..124339.17 rows=393028 width=74) (actual time=811.311..868.127 rows=391749 loops=1)
              Sort Key: item_id, start_date, allowed
              Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 29176kB
              ->  Seq Scan on mytable (cost=0.00..69370.90 rows=393028 width=74) (actual time=0.105..464.126 rows=391749 loops=1)
                    Filter: ((end_date > '2018-04-06 12:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (2928 = ANY (group_ids)))
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 1482567
Planning time: 0.756 ms
Execution time: 1098.348 ms
```

There might be room for improvement with indexes but I'm having a hard time understanding how postgres uses them, so I'm not sure what to change.

Comment: How many rows in "mytable"? How many different "item_id" values there?

Comment: Also, shouldn't you have uniqueness constraint (probably not-yet-defined unique index) in on item_id in mytable?  ... Edited: oh, I see  "PARTITION BY item_id", so this question transforms to "What is the natural, real key for your data? What should form unique index there?"

Comment: About 12 million rows in `mytable`, with about 500k different `item_id`. There is no real natural unique key for this table, it's data that's generated automatically for repeating events. I guess the `item_id` + `start_date` + `name` (field not shown here) could constitute some kind of key.

Comment: Can you post the execution plan you're getting?

Comment: Sure, added the explain analyze to the question.

Comment: _external sort  Disk: 29176kB_ => increase your `work_mem` such that these relatively small sorts happen in memory not on disk.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way of doing this?

Yes, use a temp table. There is nothing wrong with creating an indexed temp table when your query is that insane.

```
BEGIN;
  CREATE TEMP TABLE myitems ( item_id int PRIMARY KEY );
  INSERT INTO myitems(item_id) VALUES (1), (2); -- and on and on
  CREATE INDEX ON myitems(item_id);
COMMIT;

ANALYZE myitems;

SELECT item_id, other_stuff, ...
FROM (
  SELECT
      -- Partitioned row number as we only want N rows per id
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item_id ORDER BY start_date) AS r,
      item_id, other_stuff, ...
  FROM mytable
  INNER JOIN myitems USING (item_id)
  WHERE end_date > $2
  ORDER BY item_id ASC, start_date ASC, allowed ASC
) x
WHERE x.r <= 12;
```

But even better than that...

> "500k different item_id" ... "int array can contain up to 15,000 elements"

You're selecting 3% of your database individually. I have to wonder if you're not better off creating groups/tags etc in the schema itself. I have never personally had to send 15,000 different IDs into a query.

Comment: Just tried using the temporary table and it's slower, at least in the 15,000 ids case. As for creating groups in the schema itself do you mean a table with the ids I pass as an argument? I tried something like this but the performance was similar or worse than my current approach. I'll update the question with more details

Comment: No, I mean. If you have 15,000 ids normally you're storing something in the ID, like whether or not the item is a kitchen-product, and rather than storing the group_id that corresponds to "kitchen product", you're trying to find all kitchen products by their ids. (which is bad for *every* reason) What is that those 15,000 ids represent? Why isn't it stored on the row itself?

Comment: Each item belongs to multiple groups (usually 15-20 of them), so I tried storing them as an int array in mytable but couldn't figure out how to index this properly. I updated the question with all the details.